# Java: Can't get JButton to be horizontally snug around text

Tags: java, swing, width, jbutton

I have a `JButton` that is much wider than the text I put into it.  I've researched this, and I keep finding the suggestion that I use `Jbutton.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));`  But this just does not seem to work.  Also, `setMaximumSize` has no effect, although if I also set a minimum size, it does change the size of the button.  But I don't want to set the size manually.  I just want it to be less wide.  What am I missing?

Here's my code to create the button:

```
plusminus = new JButton("+");
plusminus.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image: plus button]

Thanks.

Comment: There's more information that you're not telling us, in particular what layout manager is being used by the container that holds the button. You may wish to create and post an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) that demonstrates your problem. By the way, you're not creating your GUI with NetBeans' GUI builder are you?

Comment: I'm manually making my GUI.  In this case, the layout is GroupLayout.

Comment: Well, I've found a solution to my problem that seems to work well for every L&F I've tried.  First, I have to set the insets to 0.  Then I also have to set BOTH a minimum AND a maximum set of dimensions for the button.  If the minimum dimensions are not set, maximum has no effect.  But if I set a minimum, it will always use the maximum.  Changing the insets is necessary to avoid having the '+' turn into '...' because the button doesn't think the text will fit.  I'm happy with it.

Comment: @TimothyMiller Can you add an answer with your code and the resulting screenshot?

Comment: dont tweak a component's sizing hints for the sake of a particular LayoutManager. Instead, use a LayoutManager that does supports the configuration options you want :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm manually making my GUI. In this case, the layout is GroupLayout

Then that may be part of your problem. Your JButton's size is constrained by the layout of the container that holds it. One possible solution if  you absolutely need to use GroupLayout (which I hate by the way), is to place your JButton inside of a JPanel that uses FlowLayout or some other layout that allows flexible sized components, and place this JPanel into the container that's currently holding your button. Beware though if your button's bigger than the JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

On a lark i tried negative left & right insets & unbelievably it worked.  I did not then need to mess w/ the min/max/pref sizes.  Btw my buttons are in one column of a JTable.